# She parks her car in the old spot anyway

Tags: meaning-in-context

Karen complains that her favorite parking spot was replaced by a ramp for wheel chairs. She parks her car in the ***old*** spot anyway and shoots a vlog about it.

(Retrieved from [source](https://www.google.co.kr/amp/s/www.urbandictionary.com/define.php%3fterm=Karen&amp=true))

---

I'd like to know what ***old*** means in that context.

Comment: old=the spot she had before the conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means previous.

Karen had parking spot 1 and was then changed to parking spot 2. Karen keeps parking in spot 1, and spot 2 is converted into a ramp. Karen complains about spot 2 being taken away even though she wasn’t using it.

Comment: Not correct. It says that her "favorite parking spot" (the one she uses most often) has been converted, but she goes on using it even though it is now intended for the use of  disabled people.